# AVPlayer not playing local mp4 but is web URL

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer

I currently have my mp4 file in both my Assets, and in the same folder as all my view controllers in the main directory (just to be sure).

However, I'm getting this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

On this line of code:

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
```

I know my code is working right because if I just use a regular mp4 web browser URL instead, it works fine just loads slowly (hence why I'm trying to load locally).

Here is the "full code":

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mountains", ofType: "mp4")
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)        
avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
avPlayer.volume = 0
avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none

avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by making sure I had the file added to the projects "Copy Bundle Resources" under the targets Build Phases tab.